# hbase warning about deprecated native.lib

Tags: hadoop, hbase

hadoop conf file: `opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`
when set
     `<name>hadoop.native.lib</name>`
and then start `hbase shell`, there will be four lines of warning:

```
2015-02-10 11:07:46,956 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2015-02-10 11:07:47,005 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2015-02-10 11:07:47,046 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2015-02-10 11:07:47,081 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
```

2015-02-10 11:07:47,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available

but when set 
     `<name>io.native.lib.available</name>`
and then start `hbase shell`, there will be one line of warning:

```
2015-02-10 11:07:46,956 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
```

How can I set to make it doesn't show any of this warning?

---

I'm on hadoop 2.5.2 and hbase 0.98.8 @ubuntu x64.